# sklearn - KMeans of arrays: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: scikit-learn, k-means

I am trying to do KMeans Clusterin over multidimensional features. I get ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Here is an example of what I have already tried:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(30, 4)), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
test["combined1"] = test.loc(axis=1)["a","b"].values.tolist()
test["combined2"] = test.loc(axis=1)["c","d"].values.tolist()
test.drop(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],axis=1, inplace=True)
test.head()

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0)
kmeans.fit(test)
```

The KMeans fit fails with

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    490 
    491     """
--> 492     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    493 
    494 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: What do you mean by multidimensional features?

Comment: @gorjan - a multidimensional feature is a vector of values.

Answer (score 1):

So, you pass sequences into KMeans (like `[8, 1]`) and that's why it does not work. Please check here:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans.fit

that `fit()` method allows you to use:

**X : array-like or sparse matrix, shape=(n_samples, n_features)**